# Replace entire html with ajax AND act the same as if visited page directly

Tags: ajax, shopify

I want to make ajax request to Shopify checkout page from Shopify store homepage, inject some information and display it. What Shopify do when you get redirected to checkout page is that they display loader icon and in background they do bunch of xmr requests and inject checkout information.

I can not find a way to replace current homepage with ajax response. It displays loader icon, but it won't do further xmr requests that should be trigerred by this injected html. I even tried to copy checkout page source html and replace homepage html with that using browser console, also no success.

My question is how I can replace current page html and make it acting the exact the same way as if I visited that ajax called page.

Here is how it looks html source of checkout page (removed some parts due size limit):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, height=device-height, user-scalable=0">
  <meta name="referrer" content="origin">

  

  <link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://cdn.shopify.com/shopifycloud/checkout-web/assets/">

  <title>Información - de pago</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.shopify.com/shopifycloud/checkout-web/assets/vendors~app.latest.es.187d1b212c4e881b9db2.css" crossorigin="anonymous" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.shopify.com/shopifycloud/checkout-web/assets/app.latest.es.471ab696711f9560487b.css" crossorigin="anonymous" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.shopify.com/shopifycloud/checkout-web/assets/Information~Payment~ShopPay.latest.es.aa824bd76c428cd0a36c.css" crossorigin="anonymous" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.shopify.com/shopifycloud/checkout-web/assets/Information.latest.es.1c8e26726a720c39a947.css" crossorigin="anonymous" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.shopifycdn.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.shopifycdn.com" crossorigin>
      <link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/roboto/roboto_n4.da808834c2315f31dd3910e2ae6b1a895d7f73f5.woff2?valid_until=MTY0NzM3ODQ0Nw&amp;hmac=bac2abff6393ba563d8fc7df116bdcfb84b8e16847d09a49d0f3f0e0da71266f" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
      <link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/roboto/roboto_n5.126dd24093e910b23578142c0183010eb1f2b9be.woff2?valid_until=MTY0NzM3ODQ0Nw&amp;hmac=5e4bba89500e37d34236f4de27db40ebeb2138892435a026fec5232229c5089d" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
    <style>
        @font-face {
          font-family: "Roboto";
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 400;
          src: local('Roboto Regular'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/roboto/roboto_n4.da808834c2315f31dd3910e2ae6b1a895d7f73f5.woff2?valid_until=MTY0NzM3ODQ0Nw&hmac=bac2abff6393ba563d8fc7df116bdcfb84b8e16847d09a49d0f3f0e0da71266f) format('woff2'),url(https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/roboto/roboto_n4.a512c7b68cd7f12c72e1a5fd58e7f7315c552e93.woff?valid_until=MTY0NzM3ODQ0Nw&hmac=63e69061d1319e9a4afe823fdb3a234bdaae9a51f05978d42b396d6656bdd4b9) format('woff');
        }
        @font-face {
          font-family: "Roboto";
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 500;
          src: local('Roboto Medium'), local('Roboto-Medium'), url(https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/roboto/roboto_n5.126dd24093e910b23578142c0183010eb1f2b9be.woff2?valid_until=MTY0NzM3ODQ0Nw&hmac=5e4bba89500e37d34236f4de27db40ebeb2138892435a026fec5232229c5089d) format('woff2'),url(https://fonts.shopifycdn.com/roboto/roboto_n5.ef0ac6b5ed77e19e95b9512154467a6fb9575078.woff?valid_until=MTY0NzM3ODQ0Nw&hmac=8cb52c905e8ae19b306405070e6b390ec34ea7333fc910e75fef37db05a8e8f1) format('woff');
        }
    </style>

  <style>

    html {
      font-size: 62.5%; 
    }

    body {
      background-color: #E5E5E5;
    }

    .Loading {
      overflow-y: scroll; 
    }

    .Loading #app {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    #app {
      opacity: 1;
      transition: opacity 100ms ease-in-out;
    }

    .Loading .SpinnerWrapper {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .SpinnerWrapper {
      font-size: 1.4rem; 
      opacity: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transition: opacity 100ms ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      width: 4.571428571428571em; 
      height: 4.571428571428571em;
      color: #1878b9;
      pointer-events: none;
    }

    .Spinner {
      display: block;
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      fill: currentColor;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-animation: fade-in 200ms ease-in-out 300ms forwards, rotate 500ms linear infinite;
              animation: fade-in 200ms ease-in-out 300ms forwards, rotate 500ms linear infinite;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
                transform: rotate(0);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

    @keyframes rotate {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
                transform: rotate(0);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }

    @keyframes fade-in {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="Loading">
  <div id="app"></div>
  <div id="SandboxContainer"></div>

  <div class="SpinnerWrapper">
  <svg class="Spinner" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false">
    <path d="M32 16c0 8.837-7.163 16-16 16S0 24.837 0 16 7.163 0 16 0v2C8.268 2 2 8.268 2 16s6.268 14 14 14 14-6.268 14-14h2z" />
  </svg>
</div>


  <div data-serialized-id="graphql" data-serialized-value="{&quot;95514a62243fedfcf18f495e3a6fff37d77a59e2344874afc623823ddb{\&quot;sessionToken\&quot;:\&quot;bDVWWGhDNEMyeHhhQkXdxOWU3VS9BVDJ5NXdiNHZNWWFlRGFuLzhQRU1PcTlPMlJYYUhCV1Z4UWpQQy9oK3NBbXFtWndvT1Zib3JuSklrNUJldlI4ZnlVQmRSVGNwK1VwODdqMDVEc1lkUDRNQmZjbEdneVVkbob3BhUVlBMUJIVWlTOS9FU1VDTmdVSlZ1N0xtNmIrZ1phWVQvY2VhRThCbkljU0VqeFZ4bTQvS3d5V1FLZTgzOUFaTTlEcUhrZ0tOTkpmNnRjQnpPcXl2RG1TM3lKY1V4NklWU2RjR2hpTktQaFlPeUdaM01hSVhEdldCM21rYU5aaHpzMk9Qcz0tLTNaekRyNGJWbkhUQnMwLVMwRm1LYTJ2TVBFR2dtd3B2TDRTc1E9PQ\&quot;}&quot;:{&quot;siberia&quot;:false,&quot;shop&quot;:{&quot;name&quot;:&quot; me&quot;:&quot;NegotiationResultPayload&quot;},&quot;__typename&quot;:&quot;Session&quot;}}}"></div>
  <div data-serialized-id="public-path" data-serialized-value="&quot;https:\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/shopifycloud\/checkout-web\/assets\/&quot;"></div>
  <div data-serialized-id="cart-token" data-serialized-value="&quot;cdb0daf577ce592e382babbe1587095&quot;"></div>
  <div data-serialized-id="source-token" data-serialized-value="&quot;cdb0daf577ce52e382babbe1587095&quot;"></div>
  <div data-serialized-id="checkout-session-identifier" data-serialized-value="&quot;7350eb59894c0830c65cb360e17302c&quot;"></div>
  <div data-serialized-id="session-token" data-serialized-value="&quot;bDVWWGhDNEMyeHhhQkhNTXdxOWU3VS9BVDJ5NXdiNHZNWWFlRGFuLzhQRU1PcTlPMlJYYUhC4UWpQQy9oK3NBbXFtWndvT1Zib3JuSklrNUJldlI4ZnlVQmRSVGNwK1VwODdqMDVEc1lkUDRNQmZjbEdneVVkbDJob3BhUVlBMUJIVWlTOS9FU1VDTmdVSlZ1N0xtNmIrZ1phWVQvY2VhRThCbkljU0VqeFZ4bTQvS3d5V1FLZTgzOUFaTTlEcUhrZ0tOTkpmNnRjQnpPcXl2RM3lKY1V4NklWU2RjR2hpTktQaFlPeUdaM01hSVhEdldCM21rYU5aaHpzMk9Qcz0tLTNaekRyNGJWbkhUQnMwVEYtLVMwRm1LYTJ2TVBFR2dtd3B2TDRTc1E9PQ&quot;"></div>
  <div data-serialized-id="session-finished" data-serialized-value="false"></div>  
  <div data-serialized-id="receipt" data-serialized-value="{&quot;exists&quot;:false,&quot;status&quot;:null,&quot;in_progress&quot;:null}"></div>
  <div data-serialized-id="bugsnag-config" 
  <div data-serialized-id="autocomplete-sandbox" data-serialized-value="&quot;https:\/\/checkout.shopify.com\/59158659227\/sandbox\/checkout_one_web_autocomplete&quot;"></div>
  <div data-serialized-id="analytics-iframe-url" data-serialized-value="&quot;https:\/\/yoga.com\/59158659227\/checkouts\/checkout_one_web_analytics&quot;"></div>
  <div data-serialized-id="facebook-pixel-sandbox" data-serialized-value="&quot;https:\/\/checkout.shopify.com\/59158659227\/sandbox\/checkout_one_web_facebook_pixel&quot;"></div>
  <div data-serialized-id="additional-google-analytics-script-sandbox" data-serialized-value="&quot;https:\/\/checkout.shopify.com\/59158659227\/sandbox\/checkout_one_web_additional_google_analytics_script&quot;"></div>
  <div data-serialized-id="locale" data-serialized-value="&quot;es-ES&quot;"></div>
  <div data-serialized-id="deploy-stage" data-serialized-value="&quot;production&quot;"></div>
  <div data-serialized-id="request-id" data-serialized-value="&quot;25d8faeb-f4f5-4aaf-ba68-9189747c3887&quot;"></div>
  <div data-serialized-id="login-url" data-serialized-value="null"></div>
  <div data-serialized-id="logout-url" data-serialized-value="null"></div>
  <div data-serialized-id="internal-link-origins" data-serialized-value="[&quot;https:\/\/shop.app&quot;]"></div>
  <script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/shopifycloud/checkout-web/assets/runtime.latest.es.86b6b287b2c21dd59197.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/shopifycloud/checkout-web/assets/vendors~app.latest.es.fd94d3a279887754e1f2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/shopifycloud/checkout-web/assets/Information~Payment~ShopPay.latest.es.e7da95759e894bea7d6b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/shopifycloud/checkout-web/assets/Information.latest.es.45caeef86ab72aaf2ff8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/shopifycloud/checkout-web/assets/app.latest.es.019e1cf377ae8f2fa63e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No. The answer to your question is, no.

Comment: You mean it is not possible to replace entire html and act it the same as it was visited?

Comment: I think you missed what was my real question. It was completely possible to do it before for years, only last few days they make some changes. My question is not related just to Shopify but in general, is it possible to completely replace entire html with ajax response and act it the same as if I visited ajax called page?

Comment: What about CSS files? I mean, if they are linked with relative links, then you will have issues with the styles of the webpage, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely no answer that helps really to resolve the issue, but here I can add a screenshot of the browser-console and write more text than in the comments:

[image]

It might be possible that you never see the error about the API key, then you have to dig further what might be the problem.
As everything related to Ajax is JavaScript the browser console should show you everything you need.

The errors concerning the fonts are 401-errors which means `Unauthorized`, perhaps you never see it when the html-file is opened from your server.

One issue which is not directly related to the scripts themselves might be a changed [CSP (Content Security Policy)](https://content-security-policy.com/), so that a script is existing on the Shopify server and you can call it in the browser too, but you can't include it in your own website. You might be able to resolve it by adjusting the tags for these scripts, feel welcome to specify related problems in your question if you find any indications for it. Those issues too you can see in the browser console.

Furthermore you might get hints on the [Shopify website](https://shopify.dev/) for developers, I never checked the documents they offer.